# Use of frames with vertical scrolling for product area - Good or Bad?

Tags: tables, scrolling

I wonder if using frames with vertical scrolling for product display and selection is a no-no from the usability standpoint or is it OK? Here is a wireframe where our designer suggests this solution http://wordofbuzz.com/wyf/SunTouch_Mats.html

[image: example wireframe]

Although in the above example the frames seem to make sense - I personally get a bit nervous when I work with sites that have product descriptions or other info implemented like that - you want to scroll the page and it scrolls inside the frame or vice versa you want to scroll the frame and it scrolls the entire page.

Comment: It seems all-in-one-page site pushes you to frames. Actually it could be better to re-design the site.

Comment: Thanks Alex! - it's not a site but a landing page for PPC - so everything needs to happen on one page ideally. There is a traditional ecommerce site behind that landing page with a conventional display for products/categories but it doesn't make it clear how to select/buy the right product (the nature of the product requires that you know a few specific things about your project before you can buy the right one that would fit - right now people are just calling for help or bailing)

Comment: What is the *maximum* number of items that'll appear in the scrollable table?

Comment: Jon, the total number of items for the 1st tab is 30 - i think those tabs in the wireframe have the exact products that will be showing live. There won't be any more

Comment: Are you talking about literal frames (HTML elements)? Or just scrollable areas of content? The former is typically never a great idea. The latter can work, but your big hurdle there is usability on touch screens.

Comment: thanks and yes i'm talking about the latter - scrallable content. Overall when you open this wireframe - does it strike you as user-friendly or you feel like something wrong is going on with those scroll areas or some other things.

Comment: the page will be used for PPC and will target desktop computers for now

Answer (score 2):

**Users spend 80% of their time looking at information above a page fold** (see ["Scrolling and Attention"](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/scrolling-and-attention/)).  But somehow they need to pick the right product.  So instead of thinking of this pattern as generally "good" or "bad" ask instead, "How can I get the customer to pick the right product the fastest?"

**A pattern based on questions**

If you were in a brick and mortar store and they wanted to purchase a mat, you could start out by asking "what size area do you need to heat?"  In the UI this could translate to a dropdown list with the different sizes.  After that they would need to pick the wattage.  And so on.  This pattern is called ["Cascading Lists"](http://quince.infragistics.com/Patterns/Cascading%20Lists.aspx).  This helps eliminate the noise of products for which they're not interested.

**A pattern based on browsing**

However, customers might want to browse and see what they can get based on the price instead of specifying a heating area.  Another pattern is ["Active Filtering"](http://quince.infragistics.com/Patterns/Active%20Filtering.aspx).  This pattern supplements the list you provide while minimizing how often users should spend scrolling.

**To summarize**

To answer your question, this could be confusing but not a deal breaker.  I think the more important issue is figuring out a pattern to get them to the right item without relying on them to scroll and find it in a list.

Comment: Thank you so much Jonathan - this is awesome info! Very educational and makes absolute sense.

Comment: Our earlier wireframe for a similar product included some of the items you re talking about but we had limitations in the way we could implement it and had to go that other route. http://wordofbuzz.com/wyf/Kits_4.html Thanks a lot again for the great info!

Comment: @Mark Glad to hear - your new wireframe looks much improved.